# Как убрать цвет заднего фона при скруглении

Tags: html, css

Проблема тут:

```css
.main
{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main div
{
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Как можно видеть правая левая половина со скруглением отображает задний фон, как это пофиксить?

P.S linear-gradient не предлагать!

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```css
.main {
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-clip: padding-box;  
  -moz-background-clip: padding;  
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
}
.main div {
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Подробности вот [тут](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) и вот [тут](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping)

Краткое описание:

> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the
>   appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’). Other effects
>   that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’ other than
>   ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve. The content of replaced
>   elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve. Also, the area
>   outside the curve of the border edge does not accept mouse events on
>   behalf of the element.

Comment: Ну вообще-то левая часть не скруглена

Comment: @MaximPro а, я подумал вопрос в том, почему слева видна красная полоска. Секунду

Comment: @MaximPro Для наглядности выделил зеленым, теперь оно? =)

Comment: Вы не понимаете должно быть overflow:hidden; а у вас visible

Comment: @MaximPro если поставите hidden, будет красная полоска, как в Вашем примере из-за того, что я привел в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Бекграунд не предлагать, но доп. элементы никто не запрещал ... xDD

```css
.main
{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.main:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.main div
{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}

.main div:nth-child(1) { background-color: white; }
.main div:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Вообще без контекста задачи сложно понять зачем это нужно и какими условиями можно пренебречь. Без "костылей" тут никак, а что бы костыли городить нужно понимать какой диагноз у пациента.